# How to set priority for sequence of selects in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I wonder how it could be possible to set priority for some selects in MySQL in **one query**. Let me clarify it:

For example I want to search for **apple** in My database and if it returns less than 4 records search for **orange** and if sum of apple and orange search was less than 4 search for **strawberry**.

like below

```
select * from Mytable  where Myculomn like "%apple%"
```

if returns less than 4 records this time search for orange and go on as I explained.And preferably sort it by upper priority : put search result from apple first and after that ornage and ...

I know `uninon` in mysql but its function in this occasion is quite vague to me.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional order by to get 4 rows for your criteria

```
select * 
from Mytable  
where Myculomn like "%apple%"
  OR Myculomn like "%orange%"
  OR Myculomn like "%strawberry%"
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Myculomn like "%apple%" THEN 1
    WHEN Myculomn like "%orange%" THEN 2
    WHEN Myculomn like "%strawberry%" THEN 3
    ELSE 4 END ASC
    LIMIT 4
```